# Change the horizontal size of the blocks in tikzposter

Tags: tikzposter, size, horizontal

How do I make the 3 blocks have the same horizontal size?
Something like dividing the poster into three.
Because as you can see, the poster is provided in such a way that the last "column" of blocks has a smaller horizontal size.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to give same width (=0.33 for three columns) for each column.

#### MWE

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\institute{Inst}
\author{Auth}   
\titlegraphic{Logo}
\usetheme{Basic}
\begin{document}
\maketitle 
\block{BlocktitleA}{Blocktext} 
\begin{columns}  
\column{0.33}  
\block{BlocktitleB}{\lipsum[1-4]}
\column{0.33}
\block{BlocktitleC}{\lipsum[1-4]}
\column{0.33}
\block{BlocktitleD}{\lipsum[1-4]}
\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

[image]